# Export data to word in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-word

Below is the code that creates a pdf to write a file..Every time i call the  below code it creates a pdf file to write into..My question is,is there a same method for exporting to word or for simplicity just creates a blank doc file so that i can export data into it..

```
public void showPDf() {
  iTextSharp.text.Document doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document(
    iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4);
  string combined = Path.Combine(txtPath.Text,".pdf");
  PdfWriter pw = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(combined, FileMode.Create));
  doc.Open();
}
```

Comment: You are asking by using itextsharp or just to create a doc file with some data in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1. Interop API**

It is available in Namespace `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`.

You can use Word Interop COM API to do that using following code,

```
// Open a doc file.
    Application application = new Application();
    Document document = application.Documents.Open("C:\\word.doc");

    // Loop through all words in the document.
    int count = document.Words.Count;
    for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
    {
        // Write the word.
        string text = document.Words[i].Text;
        Console.WriteLine("Word {0} = {1}", i, text);
    }
    // Close word.
    application.Quit();
```

Only Drawback is you must have office installed to use this feature.

**2. OpenXML**
you can use openxml to build word documents, try the following link,

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264572(v=office.12).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264572%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: Ans also is it necessary that there must be a word.doc file already created

Comment: no you dont need a doc file there. You can create dynamically and use can use existing ones.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try searching the web for this ?

[How to automate Microsoft Word to create a new document by using Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316384)

Answer (score 1):

There is a free solution to export data to word,

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/151789/Export-Data-to-Excel-Word-PDF-without-Automation-f

Comment: It would be great to have not just a lone link, but some summary of the document you are referencing.